# Pydantic flask validation error None is not working

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, backend

```
from flask import Flask
from pydantic import BaseModel
from flask_pydantic import validate

app = Flask(__name__)

class ReportsRequest(BaseModel):
    report_year_id: int
    offset_id: int
    limit_id: int

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@validate(query=ReportsRequest)
def get_reports(query: ReportsRequest):
    reports_controller = ReportsController()
    response = reports_controller.get_reports(query.report_year_id,
                                              query.offset_id,
                                              query.limit_id)
    return response, 200
```

when hit postman curl:
`curl --location 'http://neo-backend/v1/nbk-wealth/client-dashboard/reports/?report_year_id=25&offset_id=100&limit_id=50' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json'` 
an error is showing:
AttributeError: 'FieldInfo' object has no attribute 'is_complex'

can someone help please !

i expect 200 status code with list of reports depends on:
report_year_id,offset_id,limit_id

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem occurred in my application as well, whenever I want to implement a query check with BaseModels it throws the same error. It works fine with body. I suppose BaseModels expecting a JSON format. If you managed to solve it, can you also share how you did it?

You can replicate the error using the code from the documentation for the query checks.

```
enter code here from typing import Optional
from flask import Flask, request
from pydantic import BaseModel

from flask_pydantic import validate

app = Flask("flask_pydantic_app")

class QueryModel(BaseModel):
  age: int

class ResponseModel(BaseModel):
  id: int
  age: int
  name: str
  nickname: Optional[str]

# Example 1: query parameters only
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
@validate()
def get(query: QueryModel):
  age = query.age
  return ResponseModel(
    age=age,
    id=0, name="abc", nickname="123"
    )
```

Edit: I have just seen the issue open in the repository of the flask-pydantic, It is version issue. You should use the previous version, such as Pydantic 1.x

https://github.com/bauerji/flask-pydantic/issues/78